# Why two spaces do not collapse to a single space in a macro call?

Tags: spacing, macros

Here is my LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{A: #1}
\begin{document}

A: B0

A:  B1

\macro{B2}

\macro{ B3 }

\end{document}
```

Here is the output.

[image: Image of rendered LaTeX code]

I want to know why there is an additional space before `B3` in the output above. As far as I know multiple consecutive spaces should collapse to a single space.

But from the above output seems when one of the multiple spaces come from the macro definition and the other from the macro argument, they collapse to two spaces. Why?

Comment: For the same reason `\space\space` doesn't collapse in a single space: because it produces two space tokens. Spaces are “collapsed” only during the tokenization phase. When tokens have been formed, they are used one by one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two or more space *characters* in the file are collapsed, producing a single space *token*, but two consecutive space *tokens* make a double sized space. Here you have one space token in the macro replacement text, before `#1`, and the supplied argument starts and ends with a space token, so you get a double space.